# How to resolve "Parcel build failed. @parcel/optimizer-terser: "_" is redeclared" error

Tags: parceljs, terser

Good day everyone!

When I tried to build my parcel-based app, I encountered the following error:

```
Build failed.

@parcel/optimizer-terser: "_" is redeclared

3724 |
  > 3725 | let _ = (t1)=>t1
  >      |    ^ "\_" is redeclared
    3726 | , t;
    3727 | // src/components/visually-hidden/visually-hidden.styles.ts

  ℹ It's likely that Terser doesn't support this syntax yet.
```

Normally, I would have tried to comb through the console logs to try and debug the issues at hand, but I haven't been able to figure out where to start with this one.

Could someone help guide me in that direction please? Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was a wrong import of styled() method when extending a material ui component:

Was importing:

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
```

instead of:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
```

and was obviously using the styled-components syntax:

```
const StyledAutocomplete = styled(Autocomplete) <IStyledAutocompleteP>`
// some css here
`;
```